# Generality of tensor product in quotient construction for linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

For some finite-dimensional $\mathbb{K}$-vector space $V$, let $\bigoplus^n V$ be its $n$-fold direct sum.

In order to decide if a given collection of vectors are linearly independent, let one be interested in constructing a quotient map $q: \bigoplus^n V \to (\bigoplus^n V) / V'$  for a suitable subspace $V'$, that maps linearly dependent tuples $(v_1, \ldots, v_n) \mapsto 0 + V'$.

The subset $W \subset \bigoplus^n V$ of linearly dependent tuples $(v_1, \ldots, v_n) \in V^n$ does not form a subspace of $\bigoplus^n V$, so setting $V' := W$ does not work.

The subspace $\langle W \rangle$ generated by $W$ is the entire space. This leads to a trivial quotient for $V' := \langle W \rangle$, so this also doesn't help.

However, in the $n$-fold tensor product $\bigotimes^n V$, the terms $v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_n$ directly corresponding to the tuples in $W$ generate a subspace $X$ with $(\bigotimes^n V) / X \cong \Lambda^n(V)$.

Apart from manually deciding to construct a multilinear map $\phi: \bigoplus^n V \to \mathbb{K}$ which obviously factors through $\bigotimes^n V$, is there a way to see in advance that the tensor product is the appropriate construction to apply to 'quotient $W$ out'?

Comment: Briefly put, it looks to me that you're looking for the exterior algebra no? Because $V^{\wedge k}$ has the property that $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is linearly independent if and only if the pure blade $v_1\wedge \cdots \wedge v_k$ is non-zero.

Comment: @IvoTerek sure, one should end up with $\Lambda^n(V)$. I'm trying to see if one could get there with fewer initial assumptions, in particular multilinearity.

Comment: I don't think I "get" the question. In what sense the problem is that $W$ is not a subspace? Yes, the $n$-tuples of linearly dependent vectors $(v_1,\dots,v_n)$ do not form a subspace of $V^{\oplus n}$ but neither does the set $\{ v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n \, | \, v_1, \dots, v_n \textrm{ are linearly dependent} \}$ inside $V^{\otimes n}$... in both cases you can try to take the subspace generated by the set and this leads to different results.

Comment: @levap the subspace generated by linearly dependent tuples is the entire space, and in this case the quotient is trivial, so this doesn't help with the intended goal. But I agree with your comment about the phrasing.

Comment: @levap Yes. Passing to the tensor product involves a decision. The question is how this decision is informed; whether it is 'universal' or merely 'experimental', and in the latter case, wheter more general approaches are possible.

Comment: @user: My point is that the decision is not informed by "wanting to quotient out". You can embed the set of tuples $V^{\times n}$ (as a set) in many possible vector spaces $U$. If you denote the embedding by $i \colon V^{\times n} \rightarrow U$ then you get a map $q \colon V^{\times n} \rightarrow U / i(W)$ which gives you zero on linearly dependent tuples. You can take $U = V^{\oplus n}, U = V^{\otimes n}$, $U$ to be the free vector space generated on $V^{\times n}$ or various other choices and in all of them you "can quotient out".

Comment: I guess you can ask whether the specific embedding inside $V^{\otimes n}$ is "special" in some way but then you need to specify what do you mean by special... and this is definitely not the ability to quotient out by (the image of) $W$.

Comment: @levap You are right. The issue here is to quotient out _only_ linearly dependent tuples, while projecting others into non-zero equivalence classes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106403/discussion-between-levap-and-user).